# Salesforce Sends that are scheduled don't appear in My Tracking until send is complete

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

The Tracking page in Marketing Cloud usually shows all sends including pending sends so its easy to see whats been sent (or going to be sent).

However I have noticed that any Salesforce Sends don't appear in this list if they are scheduled and the send time hasn't been met yet.

The only way to see any of those pending sends is to visit the Interactions Page > Salesforce Sends > Pending Sends.

Is there a reason for this? Or is this a bug?